# Simplest way to make and parse json request android

Tags: java, android, json, web, android-json

I need to use a JSON api, but don't know how to do so. All the tutorials i have found are about parsing json from a file.

I need to make a request like this: http://expandurl.appspot.com/expand?url=http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FgLP0Ucg

and then it will return this

```
{"status": "OK", "end_url": "http://www.systemcomic.com/2011/06/27/the-system-506-office-forecast/", "redirects": 3, "urls": ["http://t.co/gLP0Ucg", "http://www.notquitewrong.com/rosscottinc/2011/06/27/the-system-506-office-forecast/", "http://www.systemcomic.com//2011/06/27/the-system-506-office-forecast/", "http://www.systemcomic.com/2011/06/27/the-system-506-office-forecast/"], "start_url": "http://t.co/gLP0Ucg"}
```

I just need the end_url string. How would i do this? I am also going to be doing this in a ASyncTask

Comment: Read this on how to make HTTP Request on android : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3506039/1239966

Comment: @ShivamVerma That does not help me in anyway. I do not want to make a http request, i want to make a json request and then parse it

Comment: Do you already have the json String saved ? Are you able to retrieve it successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the `JSON` you need to extract it using http request and after you get the response you then parse it to get the `end_url`.

try this to parse `end_url`:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"end_url\": \"(.+?)\",");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(You_json_string);
matcher.find();
Log.d("end_url" , matcher.group(1));
```